# Не загружаются ресурсы в MODX после переноса на локальную машину

Tags: php, modx

Всем привет! Перенёс с хостинга сайт на **modx**. И столкнулся с рядом проблем. Сначала, главная страница не загружалась вообще. Дело было в том, что я не поменял логин и пароль к базе данных, с этим разобрался, всё заработало. Теперь главная страница загружается, но ни один из ресурсов (стили, картинки, скрипты) не подтягивается, в браузере в консоли пишет, либо файл не найден (404), либо не удалось получить доступ к файлу.

Что я должен сделать, чтобы эта ошибка пропала? У меня даже вариантов нету, куда смотреть еще можно смотреть.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Не поверите, но я разобрался в чём была проблема. Сайт стоял на линукс хостинге, а у меня Windows. И везде в ссылках были относительные пути со слэшем впереди, то есть, типа такого **"/styles.css"**, стоило только убрать слэш, как всё заработало.